# Javascript is not loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have provided javascript in page(http://nextrelease.officetimer.com). Javascript for questions and answers below is not working. I have given javascipt with scr=engine1/accordion.js. Please check give solution for it. Thanks.

Comment: Is this website family to facebook.com?

Comment: [Read this article to help you learn how to debug JavaScript](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners)

Comment: @Bondye: No it is not. We got impressed by facebook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not allow to have `</script>` in your javascript

```
<script>!window.jQuery && document.write('<script src="engine1/accordion.js"></script>')</script>
```

should be

```
<script>!window.jQuery && document.write('<script src="engine1/accordion.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

Comment: @Bondye does what? at line 28 I see `document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"><\/script>')` note the slash

Comment: Yes I do agree that. For now I do not need it so removed

Comment: and also this --
[15:37:38.862] Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: *[@rel="htmltooltip"] @ http://nextrelease.officetimer.com/engine1/accordion.js:4680

Answer (score 3):

you added

```
<script src="engine1/accordion.js"></script>
```

before the  `jquery.js`

You should add your `Accordin.js`  after  `jquery.js`

like

```
<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="engine1/accordion.js"></script>
```

Comment: Suresh i added it still it is not working

Comment: Suresh for your information how is the same code is working fine in http://www.officetimer.com/

Comment: Can you please tell me ,what is the error you are getting in console ??

Comment: [15:34:34.391] TypeError: $(...).accordion is not a function @ http://nextrelease.officetimer.com/:763

Comment: I'm sure Aji.. its because if the reason I said.when you are trying to access accordin,yet jquery not intialized .

Comment: see the code properly. I used accordion after jquery only